# Classification of Subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Just trying to wrap my head around the use of subqueries. Is it correct to say that they come in three main categories:

1. **Scalar:** returns a single value
2. **Table-valued:** Returns a table, to compare or add to the outer query.
3. **Correlated:** Cannot be run as a stand-alone, must make use of data from outer query in order to run, to be executed.

Is this correct, or are there more categories? Or some subdivisions within the ones I wrote? Of course, there is, I guess, a degree of idiosyncrasy here.

Comment: This might tell you more on it http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php